# DATEDIFF function in the boundary conditions problem

Tags: sql, datediff

Could anyone help me understand the following, the result of date difference in year is 0,
but I think result should be 1 based on the condition, since the DATEADD function would return 2015-12-31, and it is greater than @ToDate 2015-01-01.
here is the link for the article, the first example
https://sqlhints.com/2015/07/10/how-to-get-difference-between-two-dates-in-years-months-and-days-in-sql-server/

```sql
DECLARE @FromDate DATETIME = '2014-12-31', 
        @ToDate DATETIME = '2015-01-01'
SELECT @FromDate 'From Date', @ToDate 'To Date',
 DATEDIFF(YEAR, @FromDate, @ToDate)
   -
 (CASE
   WHEN DATEADD(YEAR, 
           DATEDIFF(YEAR, @FromDate,@ToDate), @FromDate)
       > @ToDate THEN 1 
         ELSE 0 END) 'Date difference in Years'
```

RESULT:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNZjh.png)

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  You should also explain what you want to calculate.  There might be a simpler method.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks, I edit the question again.

Comment: . . You are not using MySQL.  You are (presumably) using SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This pretty obviously returns `0` to me:

- `DATEDIFF(YEAR, @FromDate, @ToDate)` --> 1
- `DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, @FromDate,@ToDate), @FromDate)` --> '2015-12-31'
- The `CASE` then returns `1`

So, 1-1 = 0.